# How to pass a list of arguments to facet_grid()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am trying to pass a list of arguments to `facet_grid()` to give a function more flexibility but `facet_grid()` seems to consider everything in the list as faceting variables or something. It's not returning an error but it also is not having the behavior I expected. Here is the code I tried putting together to achieve this:

```
facet_plot <- function(facet.args){
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(paste0('~', facet.args$facets), facet.args[which(names(facet.args) != 'facets')])
}
facet_plot(list(facets = 'Species', scales = 'free_x'))
```

what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_grid(~Species, scales = 'free_x')
```

I would like to be able to pass any number of additional arguments to `facet_grid()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to name the second argument so you passed it to `margin` instead of passing it to `scales` (and you need double brackets for the argument to be a vector):

```
facet_plot <- function(facet.args){
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(paste0('~', facet.args$facets), scales= facet.args[[which(names(facet.args) != 'facets')]])
}
facet_plot(list(facets = 'Species', scales = 'free_x'))
```

To be more general you could use `do.call`:

```
facet_plot <- function(facet.args){
  facet.args$facets <- paste0('~', facet.args$facets)
  ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
    geom_point() +
    do.call(facet_grid,facet.args)
}
facet_plot(list(facets = 'Species', scales = 'free_x'))
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I know I could have named the second argument within the `facet_grid()` call but I am naming it in the `facet.args` list specifically so that I could pass any number of named arguments (e.g. `facet.args = list('Species', scales = 'free_x', space = 'free_x')`).

Comment: You'll need to use `do.call` then. 1st in your function modify the 1st element of the list to incorporate the ~. Then use `... + do.call(facet.grid, facet.args)`